# java-library plugin leaking dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

My project has two modules data(com.android.library) and domain(java-library), data module depends on domain.

build.gradle(data)

```
    implementation(project(":domain"))
```

In build.gradle of domain module I have declared retrofit dependency with implementation.

```
    implementation(DevelopmentDependencies.retrofit)
```

According to docs since I am using implementation I should be unable to access Retrofit inside data module but the problem is that I am able to access Retrofit in data. module.https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Kindly suggest if I am doing something wrong.